# Loop repeats for no reason?

Tags: c++

In the following code the cout statement (sometimes) repeats without exiting the if statement and without incrementing j in j++. Sometimes the loop works just as expected (j++ gets incremented once for each cout and the statement exits). I've looked at this (and looked ...) and can't figure out what I did wrong. Any ideas?

```
   void SlipHash::outputHashTable() {
      ios_base::fmtflags fmtflg = cout.flags();
      const int size = min(nEntries, tableSize);
      for ( int i = 0, j = 0; j < size; i++ ) {
         if (hashTable[i]) {
            j++;
            cout << left << setw(27) << "SlipHash::outputHashTable[" << dec << i << "] "
                 << hex << hashTable[i] << endl;
         }
      }
      cout.flags(fmtflg);
   }; // void SlipHash::outputHashTable()
```

Comment: Doesn't the behavior depend on the contents of the hash table? If it contains zeros you don't print and don't increment `j`. What is the function of `j` in your code?

Comment: There is a path when hashTable[i] is false that simply doesn't increment `j`. That said, using operator[] overloading this could resolve to pretty much anything. Provide minimal code.

Comment: How do you know that it prints without incrementing `j`? Are you able to repeat the problem in a debugger?

Comment: You have mismatched with `i` and `j`, I think

Comment: If hashTable[i] == NULL bypass the output statement otherwise execute the code. In the debugger to code executes cout multiple times without checking termination (at the for loop) or incrementing j. I don't understand how I can get multiple executions of cout without checking for termination and incrementing j (when hashTable[i] != NULL)? i,j are not mismatched. 'i' increments through the table, j increments when hashTable[i] != NULL. Execution stops when the maximum number of table entries are output, which is typically before the table (i) has been exhausted.

Comment: Floris: j increments every time that hashTable[i] in not NULL, i.e., every time there is a valid entry in the table. i increments for every entry in the table, valid or not. When the number of entries accessed, j, is equal to the number of entries in the table, nEntry, the loop exits. The min() function is a (trivial) check to ensure that my code doesn't increment nEntries uncontrollably - it doesn't happen but I always say that I'm the worst code in town so I have to be carefully monitored. What is happening is the cout is executing as if it were in a loop by itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( int i = 0, j = 0; j < size; i++ ) {
```

It seems that you've mistyped;;

```
for ( int i = 0, j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
//                                ^
```

or

```
for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
//                      ^
```

will be correct.

Comment: Your correction will not work. Typically j, the number of entries in the hash table, is much (much) less than the size of the table. I increment j each time I see an entry and quit the table when all entries are exhausted. In your solution, I would exit early. If table size = 1024 and table entries = 3 then after the third hash table location, not the hash table entry, I would exist even if no entries have been seen.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez Oh, I didn't read your code carefully.. Then, I think there's an bug around `tableSize`. Have you ever tried to debug?

Comment: I don't understand. The only function that tableSize has is to set a maximum value for nEntries. The errant loop is around the cout statement which has no loop surrounding it. I am just puzzled (I'm using g++ 4.8.3 (cygwin). There do not seem to be any dependencies on anything in the code that would cause a single statement to unconditionally repeat itself without formally checking for loop exit, and if unsuccessful, incrementing j as appropriate. I'm not an assembly language guru but on the surface it looks like a compiler issue.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez That's why we use debugger - The Bugs are always above us, without debugger.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter in the if statement you can't have a cout without incrementation of the j var. Are you sure nEntries and tableSize and right values ? If not you can use values in memory out of the hashTable[size_table] field if value is superior, or even create infinite loop if inferior because j never reach the **size** var

Comment: The issue is that if hashTable[i] != NULL then the code increments j once and executes cout multiple times, then the code checks for the next table entry. The loop can not be infinite as long as check termination is executed and there are nEntries in the table.